# What is the purpose of the first "node" in the declaration: "typedef struct node { - - - } Node;"?

Tags: c

I am studying code examples from my professor in order to become better acquainted with linked data structures.

In our linked-list.c example the professor defines a type Node as follows:

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;
```

What's the point of the lower case **node**? I was under the impression that you could just write, for example:

```
typedef struct {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;
```

and then use Node as its own type. Does it have something to do with the fact that if you don't include a lower case node then when the compiler is evaluating the code it will not be able to understand what is meant by "struct node *next"?

Comment: Without it, it would be an unnamed struct. Note that `Node` isn't the name since it's just a typedef hack to avoid needing to use `struct node` everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean a hack? It is part of the language itself to be able to do Node instead of struct node, isn't it?

Comment: It's a hack that's so frequently used that nobody considers it a hack anymore.

Comment: None of these answers actually answer the question:  Yes, you have to use `struct node ...` for the self-referential `struct node *next` to parse.  If you're not making some kind of linked structure you can omit the `node` from `struct node`.

Comment: @BenJackson It will parse fine without the tag. Then `struct node *next;` will just declare a new (incomplete) type.

Comment: As Daniel implied, in `typedef struct { int data; struct node *next; } Node;`, the one thing that is guaranteed is that the member `next` does not point to another `Node`.  It points to some other structure type called `struct node` that is not otherwise related to `Node` at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at this declaration:

```
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
```

This can be combined into a single statement (simplifying a declaration):

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Comment: You can also use: `typedef struct node Node; struct node { int data; Node *next; };`.  The typedef names an incomplete type; the `struct node` that follows completes the incomplete type, but can use the name `Node` inside.

Answer (score 10):

> Does it have something to do with the fact that if you don't include a lower case `node` then when the compiler is evaluating the code it will not be able to understand what is meant by "`struct node *next`"?

Yes.

The `node` in `struct node` is the *tag* of the struct type. If you give the struct a tag, you can refer to that type from the moment on the tag is complete, so in

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;
```

the `struct node *next;` declares a member `next` that is a pointer to the struct type being defined. The typedef name `Node` is not available before the `;` ending the definition is reached.

If you omit the tag, you cannot refer to the type being defined in any way before the `typedef` is complete, so in

```
typedef struct {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;
```

the line `struct node *next;` declares a new, unrelated, incomplete `struct` type with the tag `node` that `next` points to.

That's valid, but nothing about `struct node` is known (unless it is defined somewhere else), so you can't use the `next` pointer without casting it to a pointer to a complete type everywhere (not quite everywhere, `Node foo; foo.next = malloc(12);` etc. would still work).

Comment: Your explanation here made a lot more sense to me than the selected correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

He is defining a *temporary* name for the node because he is using a well know technique to avoid writing `struct node` on the declaration of each struct object.

If he would just do:

```
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

you would have had to use:

```
struct node* node;
```

to declare a new node. And to avoid that you would have to define later:

```
typedef struct node Node;
```

in order to be able to declare objects like the following:

```
Node* node;
```

In the end:

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Is just a shortcut for `struct node { ... };` in addition to `typedef struct node Node;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here `struct node` is a type like `int`

and Hence

```
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}NodeVar;
```

means you are declaring a single variable Node of struct node.

like `int intVar;`

typedef is to make your code understandable.

so that when you use

```
typedef struct node Node;
```

you can use the same declaration as

```
Node NodeVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
} Node;

int main()
{
   Node a, b = {10, NULL};
   a.next = &b;

   printf("%d\n", a.next->data);
}
```

This won't compile. The compiler has no idea what a `struct node` is, other than it exists. So you might change the definition in the struct to `Node *next;`. The typedef isn't in scope before it's declared, so it still won't compile. The simple answer is to do as he said, use the `node` tag after `struct`, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The lower case 'node' is a structure type... i.e. a struct node { stuff } is a node structure containing stuff.

On the other hand, the upper case "Node" is a completely new data type which refers to a 'struct node'

Generally (though in C++ I think you can), you cannot pass around a "node" in a C program... for example as an argument to a function. Rather, you would have to pass a 'struct node' as your argument...

```
// this will throw a syntax error because "node" is not a data type, 
// it's a structure type.

void myFunc( node* arg ); 

// while this will not because we're telling the compiler we're 
// passing a struct of node

void myFunc( struct node* arg ); 

// On the other hand, you *can* use the typedef shorthand to declare 
// passing a pointer to a custom data type that has been defined 
// as 'struct node'

void myFunc( Node* arg );
```