# What is the identifier of typedef struct

Tags: c

I came up to learn linked list. But, I'm quite confused with several ways of declaring linked lists with struct.

this is one way,

```
typedef struct Nodetag {
int dataNum;
struct Nodetag* nextNode;
} NODE;
```

and this is another way not using typedef

```
struct NODE {
int dataNum;
struct NODE* nextNode;
};
```

I'm curious, when we are declaring with `typedef`, I know the `Nodetag` is used to let the compiler know what `struct Nodetag* nextNode;` is. But then, what is the actual identifier of the `struct`? `Nodetag` or `NODE`? if it is `Nodetag`, when is `NODE` used?

Comment: struct Nodetag

  is declared as NODE

Comment: what if I want to declare more objects with Nodetag? do I just declare it like this in the main function `Nodetag NODE_1;` ?

Comment: No , looking at the first example you declare it as NODE myName; Also a great answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15532501/1944441

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can optionally give a structure a tag, as in `struct Nodetag` or `struct NODE`. These tags (and union tags, and enum tags) are in a separate namespace from ordinary identifiers.

The `typedef` version creates an alias for `struct Nodetag`:

```
typedef struct Nodetag { ... } NODE;
```

Now `NODE` is a type name in the ordinary identifiers name space that is a synonym or alias for `struct Nodetag`.

Note that you can also write:

```
typedef struct Nodetag NODE;

struct Nodetag
{
    int   dataNum;
    NODE *nextNode;
};
```

The first line says 'there exists a structure type with the tag `Nodetag` and `NODE` is an alias for this type'.  The second block says '`struct Nodetag` consists of these items', listing a `NODE *` as one of the members.

---

#### C and C++ are two different languages

Note that this question is tagged C, and you are getting straight C answers (which is good).  However, if you have encountered C++, you'd find that:

```
struct Nodetag
{
    int      dataNum;
    Nodetag *nextNode;
};
```

is valid C++ and generates a type name `Nodetag` in the ordinary identifiers name space (as well as the tag `Nodetag` in the (structure) tags namespace. This is not valid in C.  You may get confused if you end up using a C++ compiler to compile C code, though.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
struct Nodetag {
    /* ... */
};
```

creates a type named `struct Nodetag`. Similarly, this:

```
struct NODE {
    /* ... */
};
```

creates a type named `struct NODE`.

In either case, you can wrap that declaration with a `typedef` declaration, creating a second name for the same type:

```
typedef struct S {
    /* ... */
} T;
```

This lets you refer to the type either as `struct S` or as `T`. (You can't call it just `S` -- though you could if you were programming in C++ rather than C.)

An equivalent way to write the above is:

```
struct S {
    /* ... */
};
typedef struct S T;
```

Note that struct tags and typedef names are in different namespaces (not in the C++ sense of the word "namespaces"), since a struct tag can only follow the keyword `struct`.  So there's no need for them to be distinct.

```
typedef struct Node {
    /* ... */
} Node;
```

Now you can refer to the type either as `struct Node` or just as `Node`.

There's no great advantage in adding a typedef like this; if you like, you can omit it and just refer to the type as `struct Node`. (But a lot of C programmers like being able to use a one-word name for a type, and a typedef is the only good way to do that (a `#define` is another way to do it, but not a good way.)

It's also possible to omit the tag name, and just use the typedef:

```
typedef struct {
    /* ... */
} Node;
```

This gives you an *anonymous* struct type, and then immediately creates the name `Node` that refers to it. But with this approach, the struct can't contain a pointer to itself, since the name `Node` doesn't become visible until after the end of the struct definition.

Comment: So, you are saying that I can use either S or T to declare an object? like `T object1;` or `S object1;` and these two would be treated equally?

Comment: In these examples, AFAICS, you can write `struct S` or `T` for the type; you can't write just `S` to refer to the types shown here (it could be a reference to an unrelated type if there's a `typedef signed char S;` somewhere else in scope, for example).  C++ does give you a simple type name `S` after you've created `struct S`, but this is C, not C++ (according to the tags).

Answer (score 0):

The first struct is called `struct Nodetag`, the second struct is called `struct NODE`.

In the first instance, a typedef has been defined that "aliases" `NODE` for `struct Nodetag`, but it doesn't change the name of the structure. What it does do is let you type, for example, `NODE*` rather than `struct Nodetag*`. It's shorthand, nothing more.

Comment: No, the first struct is called either `struct Nodetag` or `NODE`; you can't refer to it as just `Nodetag`. (You can in C++, but the question is about C.)

Comment: Quite clearly that's what I meant, if you read beyond the first line :)

Comment: I've edited your answer to say 100% clearly what you clearly understand but equally clearly misstated in the (previous edition of the) first line.

Comment: Since we're clearly in "let's be pedantic mode", the second struct is (by your reasoning) called `struct NODE`, not `NODE` - shouldn't you make that change as well?

Answer (score 0):

Structure tags and types live in different namespaces. You can have a `struct node` and also a type `node`. Structure tags must be used with the `struct` specifier/prefix to distinguish them. When you do:

```
typedef struct Nodetag {
int dataNum;
struct Nodetag* nextNode;
} NODE;
```

You are defining a new type and also defining a structure tag but you don't really need to define a type it is just for convenience. Within the structure definition, since the compiler does not know about the type until it reads the `} NODE;` part, you have to use the structure tags to refer to the structure you are defining.