# Difference between these c struct declarations?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a code looking like this :

```
struct point {
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

which can be further used like this :

```
struct point p;
p.x = 10;
p.y = 5;
```

now I came to know that this can also be written like this :

```
typedef struct{
   int x;
   int y;
} point;
```

and can be used as `point p`

The confusion started when I started learning linked-list, this is the code I saw.

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. If we can define the struct by simply using `typedef struct { ... } node` whats the use of writing `typedef struct node {.....`
2. The `node_t` at the end of the code is really confusing because from my understanding it has already defined a type `node` so we can call `node x` to create a node , then what's the need of the `node_t` or basically writing anything after the `}` what it means ?

shouldn't this work ?

```
typedef struct {
        int val;
        struct node * next;
    } node;
```

Comment: Don't you mean "struct p point" in your second code block?

Comment: You *can't* just do `node x` because `node` is a tag name.

Comment: @Happington Sir this is the code I found at http://www.learn-c.org/en/Structures, is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the first "node" in the declaration: "typedef struct node { - - - } Node;"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532403/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-first-node-in-the-declaration-typedef-struct-node)

Comment: first , You need to choose whether C++ or C.

Comment: @aelor, The tutorial uses `struct point {…};` and `typedef struct {…} point`. And the tag name should probably be the same as the typedef name.

Comment: @aelor: Of course, it is wrong!! You have defined `struct` object using `struct point p;` however your structure itself is `struct p`, there is no structure by the name of `struct point`.

Comment: @aelor, yes as several other comments on this have implied, you have declared the structure as {struct p,} then referred to it as struct point, that would give an unidentified type error.  If you want to create a structure, of type {struct p} named {p} you could do {struct p p;}  but that's a generally confusing option.

Comment: In C++, you'd always use the first form (after adding the missing `;`). The class name is a typename without the need for a `typedef` alias. But, despite the C++ tag, it looks like you're just asking about C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. If we can define the struct by simply using `typedef struct { ... } node` whats the use of writing `typedef struct node {.....`
> 2. The `node_t` at the end of the code is really confusing because from my understanding it has already defined a type `node` so we can call `node x` to create a node , then what's the need of the `node_t` or basically writing anything after the `}` what it means ?

In C, structures can have both tag and a `typedef` name. In the structure declaration:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

**`node` is a tag and `node_t` is `typedef` name**. Latter you can declare your structure variable either by using tag or `typedef` name.

```
struct node *new_node;   // OK  
node_t *head;            // OK
```

In fact, the tag and typedef name can even be same, although that's not required:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node;
```

> shouldn't this work ?

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node;
```

No. This will not work . Why?
The reason is that, when a structure has a member that points to the same kind of structure, as node does, we are required to use a structure tag. Without the `node` tag, we would have no way to declare the type of `next`.

---

**Suggested reading:** As Op is asking for good resource on data structure. Here you can go:

1. Tutorial: [Introduction to Data Structures](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/DataStructures/Lessons/).
2. Book: [Classic Data Structures](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=FdIr2prcCkgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: thankyou for the great explanation. +1, can you also suggest me a good resource from where I can learn data structures

Comment: the last code example wont work, you are using node before its defined

Comment: @sp2danny; Oops! Corrected taht and adding wxplanation.

Comment: But you said that the typedef will handle that ?? @sp2danny, is the typedef not yet defined the `node` in this code ?

Comment: for a linked list, you **need** a tag, the typedef name dont exist yet inside the struct definition

Comment: @aelor; See the edit. I added the explanation why it will not work.

Comment: that makes things clear, also please suggest me a good resource to learn data structures , thanks for coping up with patience :)

Comment: @haccks, *we are required to use a structure tag* - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78dafad2a8307ab4 :)

Comment: @Lundin but it seems c-faq doesnt talk about data-structures much ?

Comment: @aelor; For data structures, I would suggest you to raed this [book](http://www.amazon.in/Classic-Data-Structures-Samanta-Debasis/dp/812033731X). As a beginner I would recommend this [tutorial](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/DataStructures/Lessons/index.html), which is designed in such a way that you will enjoy :)

Comment: @aelor There's 26 pages only on the topic of structs, unions and enums.

Answer (score 4):

The third block of code, which you seem to have a question about, has a redundant identifier.

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

is identical to

```
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node node_t;
```

They're identical, but merged into the same line.  The syntax around a `typedef` is

```
typedef [original name] [new name];
```

Normally, when we typedef a struct, the ONLY way to reference it afterwards would be the typedeffed name (in the first code example, you could only access it by node_t) while a slightly more redundant declaration allows for accessing by the "struct node" variable type too.

To answer your other question the `node_t` that confused you is what you can refer to the struct as... for example

```
node_t node1;
struct node node2;
```

Are the two valid declarations for a node struct.

Comment: so if I write `typedef struct {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;` will it be correct ?

Comment: No, you're calling it "struct node*" on the inside.  At that point, there's no such thing as a "struct node."  You can have it as a void pointer, and cast it as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot happington, for the first time in my extra small career of `c` I am feeling so clear

Comment: Then, as a small token of thanks.  Please remove the c++ tag.  c++ is NOT c

Comment: I just added the autotags given by SO. i ll remove it straight away .

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can also use 'struct p' by typedefing it using 'struct p typedef P;'. It sometimes makes me confused when typedef a complex function pointer.
I don't know the reason why the C std. support such a syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my explanation.

```
struct
{
   int i;
};
```

declares an unnamed structure and apparently there is no real usage of this. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
struct
{
   int i;
} T;
```

now T is an object in the given scope and type is unnamed.

```
struct TT
{
   int i;
} T;
```

declares a structure TT and an object T. You can use TT to create more objects. The best way to think about this is, just consider struct TT{ int i} as a single type such as double.

```
typedef struct TT
{
   int i;
};
```

has the same meaning as (at least in nowadays compiler. I'm not sure about the older ones)

```
struct TT
{
   int i;
};
```

and

```
typedef struct
{
   int i;
} TT;
```

declares a type TT (not an object) for the given structure as you are using typedef int Int;

Hope this resolves the mess.